# rspec stubbing passing the same arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec

Sample code:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(abc)
    @abc = abc
    @bind = bar
  end
  def bar
    SomeClass.new(@abc)
  end
end
```

Now I want to stub bar using rspec and custom stub:

```
allow('Foo').to receive(:bar).and_return(FakeBar.new)
```

The issue is that the `FakeBar.new` has to be initialize with the same arguments `:bar` receives. Is it possible to get a copy of params passed to `:bar` at the time we are stubbing and reuse them in the stub class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do what you're doing (probably there is a simpler way), but for what it's worth:

```
allow("Foo").to receive(:bar) { |arg1, arg2| FakeBar.new(arg1, arg2) }
```

[RSpec docs, block stub implementation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation)